# How to send image in contact us email in Magento2?

Tags: magento2

How to send image in contact us email in Magento 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

1.Create di.xml in Vendor/Module/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\Contact\Model\Mail" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Mail" />
</config>
```

2.Create file Mail.php inside Vendor\Module\Model and append here one more function **->addAttachment($filePath, $fileName)** like as below

```
   <?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\App\Area;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Mail extends \Magento\Contact\Model\Mail
{
    /**
     * @var ConfigInterface
     */
    private $contactsConfig;

    /**
     * @var TransportBuilder
     */
    private $transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var StateInterface
     */
    private $inlineTranslation;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    protected $fileSystem;

    /**
     * Initialize dependencies.
     *
     * @param ConfigInterface $contactsConfig
     * @param TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param StateInterface $inlineTranslation
     * @param StoreManagerInterface|null $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        ConfigInterface $contactsConfig,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager = null,
        Filesystem $fileSystem

    ) {
        $this->contactsConfig = $contactsConfig;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->fileSystem          = $fileSystem;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(StoreManagerInterface::class);
    }

    /**
     * Send email from contact form
     *
     * @param string $replyTo
     * @param array $variables
     * @return void
     */
    public function send($replyTo, array $variables)
    {
        /** @see \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post::validatedParams() */
        $replyToName = !empty($variables['data']['name']) ? $variables['data']['name'] : null;

        /** image path of attachment and CustomImage is the directory inside media directory***/
        $path = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('CustomImage');

        /**** Image name ***/

        $fileName = $imagename;

        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        try {
            $transport = $this->transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->contactsConfig->emailTemplate())
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                        'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars($variables)
                ->setFrom($this->contactsConfig->emailSender())
                ->addTo($this->contactsConfig->emailRecipient())
                ->setReplyTo($replyTo, $replyToName)
                ->addAttachment($filePath, $fileName)
                ->getTransport();

            $transport->sendMessage();
        } finally {
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to create a custom field for uploading image in contact form and that uploaded image I have to send in contact email how it will be done ?

Comment: is your image uploading in directory or you need code for upload image in directory too ?

Comment: I have to code for custom image field in contact form and uploading in directory too and getting that image in mail

Comment: if you are getting that image in mail then what is problem

Comment: image should be upload from contact form

Comment: add code in your controller like as i did https://github.com/ansarhusain7/Custom-mail-with-attachment-magento2/blob/master/CustomForm/MailAttachment/Controller/Index/Submit.php for upload image

Comment: I am getting this error after adding addAttachment() method in mail -              Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder\Interceptor::addAttachment() in E:\xampp\htdocs\magento225\app\code\Magenticians\Modulecontact\Model\Mail.php:92